# Google jQuery Chart API Not Working With Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-api

I am having trouble getting a line chart from the google API to work with tabs not shown by default.  When i run the the charts alone on the first tab, they appear, but when I place them on tab 2+ it will not appear.  Any idea why this doesnt work?  This is the API I am using

```
http://www.google.com/jsapi
```

I am using the jquery-ui-1.8.13 for the tabs functionality.  Here is an abbreviated part of my code:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
...
//load the charts
...
<div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1"><div id="visualization" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div> </div>
                <div id="tabs-2"><div id="visualization2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div> </div>
                <div id="tabs-3">...</div>
            </div>
```

Any idea why it will not show on any tab but the first one?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? I'm having trouble with both axis label not displaying in charts after the first tab.